# Java Selenium can't find Firefox

Tags: java, linux, selenium, firefox, geckodriver

Asked the question on this platform as well: https://www.reddit.com/r/selenium/comments/mig603/moved_to_linux_cant_get_my_web_scraper_to_work/

I used to be on Windows, swapped to Linux Pop!_OS 20.10. Since i swapped, i can't get my WebScraper to work anymore, the problem seems really simple but i can't resolve it.

Code:

```
    File pathBinary = new File("/lib/firefox/");
    FirefoxBinary firefoxBinary = new FirefoxBinary(pathBinary);

    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "/geckodriver_linux");
    // System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/home/benij/Software/chromedriver_linux64/chromedriver");

    // Removing unnecessary JavaScript errors/warnings.
    System.setProperty(FirefoxDriver.SystemProperty.DRIVER_USE_MARIONETTE, "true");
    System.setProperty(FirefoxDriver.SystemProperty.BROWSER_LOGFILE, "/dev/null");

    // FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile("");
    FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
    profile.setPreference("dom.webdriver.enabled", false);
    profile.setPreference("useAutomationExtension", false);
    profile.setPreference("permissions.default.image", 2);
    profile.setPreference("dom.ipc.plugins.enabled.libflashplayer.so", false);
    profile.setPreference("webgl.disabled", true);
    FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
    options.setProfile(profile);
    options.setBinary(firefoxBinary);
    // options.addArguments("--headless");

    // WebDriver webDriver = new ChromeDriver();
    WebDriver webDriver = new FirefoxDriver(options);

    webDriver.manage().window().maximize();
    // Sets max loading time for a website.
    webDriver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Specified firefox binary location does not exist or is not a real file: /lib/firefox
at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:504)
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.Executable.<init>(Executable.java:43)
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxBinary.<init>(FirefoxBinary.java:123)
at Main.main(Main.java:24)
```

File structure:

```
benij@benij:/lib/firefox$ ls
application.ini     gmp-clearkey        libmozwayland.so  libssl3.so
browser             gtk2                libnspr4.so       libxul.so
crashreporter       libfreeblpriv3.chk  libnss3.so        minidump-analyzer
crashreporter.ini   libfreeblpriv3.so   libnssckbi.so     omni.ja
defaults            liblgpllibs.so      libnssutil3.so    platform.ini
dependentlibs.list  libmozavcodec.so    libplc4.so        plugin-container
distribution        libmozavutil.so     libplds4.so       Throbber-small.gif
firefox             libmozgtk.so        libsmime3.so
firefox.sh          libmozsandbox.so    libsoftokn3.chk
fonts               libmozsqlite3.so    libsoftokn3.so
```

Also when running "firefox" in a terminal firefox is started, so normally i shouldn't have to tell my OS where firefox is, since it is in the path. But when removing the FirefoxBinary this happens:

Exception without FirefoxBinary:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Cannot find firefox binary in PATH. Make sure firefox is installed. OS appears to be: LINUX
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: 'benij', ip: '192.168.1.108', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '5.11.0-7612-generic', java.version: '15.0.2'
Driver info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxBinary.<init>(FirefoxBinary.java:100)
at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:362)
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxOptions.getBinary(FirefoxOptions.java:216)
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.toExecutor(FirefoxDriver.java:187)
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:147)
at Main.main(Main.java:46)
```

Answer (score 0):

The Problem is ,Selenium not able to find the Firfox exe.In Linux usually it located at /usr/bin/firefox.

Add below code

```
option.setBinary(FireFoxExePath);
```

where FirefoxExePath is the string  storing the path where FireFox EXe is there. You many put a condition OS wise so that it wont be hardcoded andworks for all OS.

As per you code in Line 1 the path binary you have set as lib/firefox. Change it it to

```
"lib/firefox/firefox"
```

Answer (score 0):

Got past this problem by installing a fresh copy from firefox without apt but from here: https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/new/
When extracting the file, its quite a bit different from the folder created by apt. There is a "firefox-bin" file and a "firefox" file. Both seem to get recognized as firefox binaries. Ultimately it just resulted in different problems for me, so i am switching to Chrome which almost worked out of the box.